# wordpress - change the order of tags from the_tags()

Tags: wordpress, tags

I'm currently getting the list of tags like this:

```
<?php the_tags('<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>'); ?>
```

Which displays them alphabetically. I need to change the order though. I only have 4 possible tags and I know the order they should go in, but it's not alphabetical.

EDIT: I posted the wrong code. This is how the tags are getting displayed:

```
<?php wp_tag_cloud('smallest=9&largest=9&format=flat' );?>
```

I need to display that in custom order 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be able to get the tags first like this and then do something with them:

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  $arr = array();
  $possible_tags = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
  foreach ($possible_tags as $possible) {
    if (array_search($possible, $posttags) !== FALSE) {
      array_push($arr, $possible);
    }
  }
  echo '<ul><li>'. implode('</li><li>', $arr) . '</li></ul>';
}
```

Docs at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags

Comment: Great response. This looks like it should work on individual posts. I actually need to order the tag cloud (see edit in original question). Sorry.

Comment: How about `$posttags = wp_tag_cloud('smallest=9&largest=9&format=array' );` (and the rest of the code being the same)?

Comment: hmm... that ends up printing out an empty unordered list.

Comment: Are your tags equal to 9 in count as you specified in your example by using smallest and largest? can you do a var_dump maybe on `$posttags`?

Comment: smallest and largest refer to text size, not count. I have 4 tags

Comment: Try a var_dump on $posttags with the wp_tag_cloud? is it an array or what?

Comment: Did you forget the extra "t" in "$posttags"?

Comment: array(4) { [0]=> string(147) "a" [1]=> string(144) "b" [2]=> string(146) "c" [3]=> string(137) "d" }

Comment: Are you using my current code above? And are you var_dump'ing $possible_tags by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This would require editing the `the_tags` function. I think they're currently ordered by their ID. You could possibly rejig the IDs (deleting, re-adding) to change the order. This would avoid extra code.